# Point AWS Route53 domain name to MailChimp landing page?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, mailchimp

I'm having a strange issue, and I'm trying to sort out if MailChimp just doesn't allow what i'm trying to do, or if I'm doing something wrong.

I simply want to **point a domain name I purchased via AWS (Route53) towards a landing page I created on MailChimp**. When I go into MailChimp to edit my landing page URL, I've successfully verified the custom domain I want to use, but it will ONLY let me point a sub-url to the landing page (e.g. [www.mydomain.com/add-something-here](http://www.mydomain.com/add-something-here)); it will not let me just point my .com to the page without the subfolder name.

Any idea why this is? I created an A Record and a www CName Record in my Route53 dashboard - the A record points to the provided MailChimp IP address, CName points to the provided Mailchimp URL. That said, when I then navigate to [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com), I get a MailChimp error that says:

> It looks like you're trying to reach a page that was built by
> Mailchimp but is no longer active. Want to know more about us? Visit
> mailchimp.com

Any idea why this is? Or does MailChimp just not give me the option to direct my domain name to the landing page?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you figure it out?